# Drupal 7 Search Api facet widgets in multiple blocks

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, facet

I am using Drupal [Search Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) module, I have configured all the needed stuffs. But right now am having the exposed filter only in the specified page. But I want to display the filters as well as home page. Is there any way to do that.

I have tried this [sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/batje/1570344) project, it nice but it shows the another block in the same page, I can't access this page in another region or page.

Can you guys please help me out in this case, thanks in advance.